# Using the Crashlog to Debug iOS (the basics)

Tags: ios, crash, crash-log

Alright, I'm stupid new at this. Can anyone point me in the direction of how to read the crashlog and use it to debug an app? I'm not looking for anyone to solve the problem. I'm just hoping for advice on how to go about learning to fix it myself so I don't have to bug folks on places like this every couple of days.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xdde40cfb
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31134f94 objc_msgSend + 44
1   Bobble_Head                     0x000c97aa 0x20000 + 694186
2   Bobble_Head                     0x000ca096 0x20000 + 696470
3   UIKit                           0x33b2d6b4 -[UIAccelerometer _acceleratedInX:y:z:timestamp:] + 192
4   UIKit                           0x338d1286 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 2574
5   UIKit                           0x338d0708 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 48
6   UIKit                           0x338d00dc _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5820
7   GraphicsServices                0x341c0224 PurpleEventCallback + 876
8   CoreFoundation                  0x310a651c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
9   CoreFoundation                  0x310a64be __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
10  CoreFoundation                  0x310a530c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3102849e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
12  CoreFoundation                  0x31028366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
13  GraphicsServices                0x341bf432 GSEventRunModal + 130
14  UIKit                           0x338fee76 UIApplicationMain + 1074
15  Bobble_Head                     0x000a82dc 0x20000 + 557788
16  Bobble_Head                     0x00021a90 0x20000 + 6800

.
.
.

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00257ba0    r1: 0x000e1df4      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x30bddcf9
    r4: 0xdde40cfb    r5: 0x0028c430      r6: 0x2fe1d7e4      r7: 0x2fe1d724
    r8: 0x3df57800    r9: 0x00030072     r10: 0x0028afe0     r11: 0xbf802700
    ip: 0x776f6873    sp: 0x2fe1d5dc      lr: 0x000c97b1      pc: 0x31134f94
  cpsr: 0xa00f0030

Binary Images:
   0x20000 -    0xfffff +Bobble_Head armv7  <55ac25ad8d173c9ab6c6ef5bd996cc21> /var/mobile/Applications/CE8D156C-1FF9-45AE-B60A-6958A21BC02D/Bobble_Head.app/Bobble_Head
0x2fe1f000 - 0x2fe40fff  dyld armv7  <4a817f3e0def30d5ae2032157d889c1d> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3043e000 - 0x30488fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x3048a000 - 0x3048ffff  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib armv7  <3c1cc3175c403ace8fcbd3826bd43807> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/libGPUSupportMercury.dylib
0x304de000 - 0x30591fff  iTunesStore armv7  <0b61336b65033857a22ce498c653636b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
0x30758000 - 0x30784fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x30785000 - 0x30786fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <66e985f3eea03ef08afb7cf4c153f76e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x3078d000 - 0x30790fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x30793000 - 0x30795fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x3079d000 - 0x307acfff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <ca5b10014b473d2eaec5c48d89ee1b54> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x30887000 - 0x30888fff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x30889000 - 0x30892fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x30894000 - 0x30a12fff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x30a13000 - 0x30a1ffff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x30a62000 - 0x30a69fff  MailServices armv7  <ab2388ce733e38b7a261273a401bbbf1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x30ac1000 - 0x30acdfff  Accounts armv7  <79f22009b1173e1e81f70fc5c0410119> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x30ace000 - 0x30bf1fff  PhotoLibrary armv7  <7549c116c4d632a7b078cd8e7a28ac72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework/PhotoLibrary
0x30bf2000 - 0x30c0afff  iAd armv7  <9e9184ed0077317a97b879c3df950316> /System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework/iAd
0x30c0b000 - 0x30ce3fff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x30ce4000 - 0x30cebfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <0703f561f9a038b6850d6e93bba7e5f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x30d31000 - 0x30d3dfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x30e0c000 - 0x30e12fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x30eed000 - 0x30eedfff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30eee000 - 0x30ef5fff  SpringBoardUI armv7  <8f278b49685e3db68ac63c60011b14dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardUI.framework/SpringBoardUI
0x31019000 - 0x31130fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x31131000 - 0x311f7fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x311f8000 - 0x311fdfff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x31200000 - 0x31235fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x31236000 - 0x313f3fff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x313f4000 - 0x313f9fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x313fa000 - 0x313fffff  ApplePushService armv7  <f424c0340de637c08bbeb4f3bd8c6eaf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x31546000 - 0x31583fff  FTServices armv7  <28ed78e01a77388cb4c0f2f6ec33482c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x3158e000 - 0x3165dfff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <49607ffe4ee9389494285a213e392924> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x3165e000 - 0x3169dfff  QuickLook armv7  <802b1092542a3017a0380632502610d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x316a5000 - 0x3173efff  EventKit armv7  <d67aa1508ee7306b8e2a45c76ffddff0> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x3173f000 - 0x31742fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x31839000 - 0x3184ffff  EAP8021X armv7  <fffe86a22bc434a6ae84f23bfecef9d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x31854000 - 0x31890fff  iCalendar armv7  <f2836083051132d3aa40ad82d7f73aea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x31895000 - 0x3189bfff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3189c000 - 0x318b6fff  TelephonyUI armv7  <6d9df4a85ca23acfa0799076fb8e5944> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUI.framework/TelephonyUI
0x318b7000 - 0x318d0fff  Twitter armv7  <8fe6d77b99b43d2287e9c51bc4b22456> /System/Library/Frameworks/Twitter.framework/Twitter
0x318d3000 - 0x31947fff  MediaControlSender armv7  <87315c54b2293ab589950341ff91b45d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x31a2e000 - 0x31a3ffff  AirTraffic armv7  <c9eb888c1bd1322cbda5b01d41be0c7d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x31a40000 - 0x31a4bfff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x31ac0000 - 0x31ad1fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x31ad2000 - 0x31aeafff  ChunkingLibrary armv7  <c73a4b4b38ae3702bc1feae489d31634> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x31aeb000 - 0x31af8fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x31af9000 - 0x31b39fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x31c99000 - 0x31d69fff  WebKit armv7  <6ff2796c2f933050ac6ecdee9fc6a216> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x31d7e000 - 0x31d96fff  Notes armv7  <724966ed5cd4395cb70f9c996b123f53> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x31dbf000 - 0x31dc4fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <2bb524b3bb3c3eb2932ce13b655b7c7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x31e3c000 - 0x31e3cfff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x31f5a000 - 0x31f5cfff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x322d2000 - 0x322d2fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x322f6000 - 0x32305fff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x3230e000 - 0x32accfff  WebCore armv7  <814351ff217e3425a8e532c2e2251f73> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x32acd000 - 0x32ae1fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <65682d21486836a3aa3e17b9461e7b3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x32ae2000 - 0x32b2cfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <5e0a131bbfec305ea01f9e01f486da63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x32b2d000 - 0x32b4afff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x32b4b000 - 0x32baefff  IMCore armv7  <6e26e99b9b5f3829a8486ffd8c64f0d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x32bb2000 - 0x32bd0fff  BulletinBoard armv7  <6b4e1e4680c030cb9a0ced9ff69a711f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BulletinBoard.framework/BulletinBoard
0x32bde000 - 0x32be2fff  IOSurface armv7  <6ae77a40f8e93f28bc466ca93f5675d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x32c16000 - 0x32d5ffff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x32e5f000 - 0x32e62fff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x32e63000 - 0x32e64fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x32e70000 - 0x32ef3fff  MapKit armv7  <e39706ac199134a497954e1f1d6d7245> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x32f33000 - 0x32f33fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x32f86000 - 0x32fcefff  CoreMedia armv7  <eb1f503312be3c93b07b2d0d25177000> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3312d000 - 0x33131fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x334cc000 - 0x334cffff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x334d6000 - 0x33506fff  ContentIndex armv7  <7a64670bb2ff3ee39ddee1dc1c72f92d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x3350f000 - 0x336f3fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x337ab000 - 0x337e7fff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x337ea000 - 0x33847fff  StoreServices armv7  <628fbbc73ed93730962c53bfbfde6794> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x338b4000 - 0x338b8fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x338b9000 - 0x338bcfff  ActorKit armv7  <434c756a6b053f4ba3c954cfccddbf59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x338cd000 - 0x33d6ffff  UIKit armv7  <d72bcc68e76a3a55a963590cdcffe8cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x33db7000 - 0x33dccfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x33dcd000 - 0x33dcffff  OAuth armv7  <3ccc08bd120934baba4572552dc18ee4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x33dd0000 - 0x33dd2fff  libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7  <808518e0fbf539af8489f028ca5198c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x33dd3000 - 0x33dd7fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x33dd8000 - 0x33de2fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x33deb000 - 0x33f10fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x33f20000 - 0x33f69fff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x33f6c000 - 0x34022fff  AVFoundation armv7  <35cb7a0eb1dc3554a777c1cc11cb0415> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x34023000 - 0x340cdfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x340da000 - 0x340f3fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x340f4000 - 0x3410dfff  OpenAL armv7  <b038673e21c132ff9d0c4de6502efea5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/OpenAL
0x3412a000 - 0x3416dfff  ImageCapture armv7  <e21827dfb65032e1aa7fdf22a4f37fc4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageCapture.framework/ImageCapture
0x3418e000 - 0x341bafff  ACTFramework armv7  <0bc67086eb7b31d090bb4c9c7a54bfb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ACTFramework.framework/ACTFramework
0x341bb000 - 0x341c5fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <e21a6e61bdd136b6805a9e3abe2e3d1f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3426e000 - 0x3426efff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x342a6000 - 0x342aafff  FTClientServices armv7  <21de970d7ebb3e7fb502a0a5451b0806> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x342ab000 - 0x342b2fff  MediaRemote armv7  <42dc1b43dabd3692b97d6aacfbdf0449> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x34304000 - 0x34347fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3437d000 - 0x3438efff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x34399000 - 0x343a5fff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x343a6000 - 0x343f4fff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x34441000 - 0x3452ffff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3453b000 - 0x34551fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <7ac5560851ce3cb3981068092074b409> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x3458c000 - 0x34612fff  CoreMotion armv7  <6a9355d5a8e238b5b8f193605d509e15> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x3462c000 - 0x34684fff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x346a4000 - 0x346acfff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x346b1000 - 0x346d6fff  OpenCL armv7  <ec915bfc3f7633dda61b5fc87459119b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x346fc000 - 0x3470bfff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <70ac33720f513f0f97ea2279260678ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x34853000 - 0x34915fff  Celestial armv7  <2a59586b0ae937c3b25fe526924aa885> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x34916000 - 0x34a89fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <63cdf8f9c66d36e7a4e69e2f6cae854f> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x34acd000 - 0x34ae4fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <bd20a05587783a8e9596eef1d3615ea7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x34ae5000 - 0x34aebfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x34aec000 - 0x34bbbfff  IMGSGX535GLDriver armv7  <6108ea3ab17835bc9092b27bd44703d5> /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX535GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX535GLDriver
0x34bd8000 - 0x34e99fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34e9a000 - 0x34efefff  MessageUI armv7  <b74d79ea691a35ada276f063b7217a20> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x34f52000 - 0x34f59fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x34f5a000 - 0x34f95fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x350d1000 - 0x350d7fff  IAP armv7  <17eddbf5590d3cb88d4acbda27447f5b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x350d8000 - 0x3561cfff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x3562b000 - 0x35635fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x35636000 - 0x356a6fff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x356a7000 - 0x356abfff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x356ac000 - 0x356e1fff  DataAccess armv7  <89fd0c22338b37538cf61803a0bca9e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x356e2000 - 0x35727fff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x35780000 - 0x35780fff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x35781000 - 0x35927fff  CoreData armv7  <b0215b6d4d143859a2b313ecade095ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x35928000 - 0x359c5fff  PhotoLibraryServices armv7  <da975ffd2e003b6a898a7d60b5273d0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
0x359f5000 - 0x35a74fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x35a75000 - 0x35ac6fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x35ad4000 - 0x35afdfff  ToneLibrary armv7  <7c1be74cc7833f3db25638fbc4ed55b8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneLibrary.framework/ToneLibrary
0x35afe000 - 0x35b02fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x35b03000 - 0x35b41fff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x35baa000 - 0x35bf3fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x35bf4000 - 0x35ce5fff  QuartzCore armv7  <a2afbe6483683d05ad51b106f98776e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x35d7c000 - 0x35da0fff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x35da1000 - 0x35e47fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <da424fecc66e3628ab03378ae80b38fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x35eb5000 - 0x35eb6fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x35ec0000 - 0x35ec6fff  MediaStream armv7  <99a5a80a06f5367c93a7911bf257bf20> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaStream.framework/MediaStream
0x35f67000 - 0x35fb3fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <e8eb52ca5fe33c7488a33efd222e7804> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x35fb4000 - 0x35fcafff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x35fd3000 - 0x35fd7fff  CertUI armv7  <f503892ef60e36108d28d8f9d6144d2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x35fe3000 - 0x36003fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x36004000 - 0x36033fff  MMCS armv7  <527ed7a3b4753ead89e30be95dc3c590> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MMCS.framework/MMCS
0x360b1000 - 0x360b2fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x360b3000 - 0x360d6fff  MobileSync armv7  <e42604c550283f4aa517ae8f108b340f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x36654000 - 0x3665afff  XPCObjects armv7  <dc568831fa5b3b22b673c62bc9d21d16> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x36c0d000 - 0x36c23fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x36c91000 - 0x36d3efff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x36d52000 - 0x36d8efff  IMFoundation armv7  <77bb4365a65b32a49523b03da0340dbc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x36e5e000 - 0x36e95fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x37021000 - 0x37065fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x37066000 - 0x3706efff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x3707f000 - 0x37111fff  HomeSharing armv7  <969a71b143ce3b84a41af74119131ebd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x37188000 - 0x3718efff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x37197000 - 0x371cbfff  MIME armv7  <d30292ea8f7e360fa5f5d5b1b62b602d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x37283000 - 0x37299fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x372a3000 - 0x372c6fff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x372c7000 - 0x374f4fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <ec9bc89489763c6c93f86c5c490b2d69> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x37529000 - 0x3755cfff  CoreMediaStream armv7  <f5a0b436d07a3bcea37b43627249177b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaStream.framework/CoreMediaStream
0x3755d000 - 0x3755dfff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x37571000 - 0x37637fff  GLEngine armv7  <6617f2b4ee283469a5595129889ff049> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x3763d000 - 0x3765cfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x37664000 - 0x376b5fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x376c7000 - 0x376c8fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x37730000 - 0x37807fff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x37808000 - 0x3793ffff  MusicLibrary armv7  <545ed15c56a53f5f9f893706c7af4ab7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x379b8000 - 0x379b9fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7850befd26b630f183ee326aaadd7b34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x379ba000 - 0x37a46fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x37a49000 - 0x37a4dfff  Marco armv7  <8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x37a81000 - 0x37a84fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x37a87000 - 0x37b00fff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x37b01000 - 0x37b04fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x37bdd000 - 0x37c15fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x37c16000 - 0x37c6cfff  GMM armv7  <6b2f7e1aa6be3d69b4c4cf54ed960602> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x37ca3000 - 0x37cb2fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x37cb3000 - 0x37cb9fff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x37cbe000 - 0x37ce7fff  AppleAccount armv7  <2ba44023410231fcb3f72f762ea3ce6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x37e6b000 - 0x37fb0fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x37fb7000 - 0x38065fff  Message armv7  <b8221d43401d315fb84398b7aa570fc1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go through these two articles and you'll have all the knowledge you need to find and squash crash bugs

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1
http://www.raywenderlich.com/10505/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-2